# Ruby on Rails: Having problems selecting correct parameters for a method depending on context the is method used

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I am working on a application where Users can list their in-game items to trade with other Users. A user's profile url would be something like this:

/users/1/index

And their user listings profile would be something like

/users/1/listings/1

All other resources nested under users would be the same as the latter.

I am trying to implement a method that is called by a before_filter callback that checks to see if a user has blocked or is blocked by the user who owns the profile and respective nested resources such as ability to message them, view their listings etc. If either has blocked each other, then they redirected to the root page of the application. This is the method that I use for the before_filter:

```
def blocked_relationships
  if blocked?
     redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

I used another method that checks the state of the relationships between the two users.
This is the method I found and worked on after some research courtesy of the Rails Recipes book:

```
 def blocked?
    Relationship.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, other_user_id: params[:user_id], status: "blocked") ||
    Relationship.exists?(user_id: params[:user_id], other_user_id: current_user.id, status: "blocked")
end
```

The problem I have is that this method only works, for example, when User 1 is looking at User 2's items, messages, listings etc. because the url:

/users/2/listings [or items or etc]

will contain a params that makes reference to the user as params[:user_id]. params[:id] in this case and context will refer to the listings id.

BUT, if I am User 1 and I have blocked User 2 and visit User 2's profile, this method will not work because the url /users/2/index will use params[:id] to instead of params[:user_id].

I've been thinking about how to implement this in a DRY way but I can't seem to solve my problem other than doing something like this:

```
def blocked?
  if params[:user_id].blank?
    Relationship.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, other_user_id: params[:id], status: "blocked") ||
    Relationship.exists?(user_id: params[:id], other_user_id: current_user.id, status: "blocked")
  else
    Relationship.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, other_user_id: params[:user_id], status: "blocked") ||
    Relationship.exists?(user_id: params[:user_id], other_user_id: current_user.id, status: "blocked")
  end
end
```

I also considered the possibility that I'm not even implementing my blocking feature correctly, but before I address that issue, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to solve this problem. Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated and I would be happy to add anymore information for clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not `other_id = params[:user_id] || params[:id]`? This is a way to override `:id` when `:user_id` is present.

About your blocking feature though, to me I'd like to see a user even if I've blocked them. I'd create a `blocked_by_user_id` field on the Relationship to see who did the blocking and only disallow the blocked party from seeing the user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to checkout authorization gems for rails like [`cancan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or related (it's not my favorite but the most popular). However, you could handle it like this:

```
class User
  has_many :relationships, 
  scope :accessible_by,
    ->(user) { where.not id: user.relationships.where(status: :blocked).pluck(:other_user_id) }
end
```

Then use the relationship `User.accessible_by(current_user)` on your controller instead of plainly `User` to retrieve resources. For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.accessible_by(current_user)
    # bleh
  end

  def show
    @user = User.accessible_by(current_user).find(params[:id])
    # etc
  end
end
```

When the resource is nested under a user you could do this:

```
class Users::PicturesController < UsersController
  def index
    @pictures = User.accessible_by(current_user)
      .find(params[:user_id]).pictures
  end

  def show
    @picture = User.accessible_by(current_user)
      .find(params[:user_id]).pictures.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When a user tries to access a resource that can't view, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will be raised, so you should handle it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNorFound, with: :rescue_not_found

  private

  def rescue_not_found
    redirect_to root_path, 
      notice: 'You can\'t access that with your current priveleges. '
  end
end
```